# QT QODBC Postgres how disable all logs

Tags: postgresql, qt, odbc

There is an application written in QT 5.15, Linux, it connects to the Postgres 9.6 database using QSqlDatabase, driver QODBC. Everything is fine, but when connecting to the database, a log file with the name "app-process-id.log" appears in the directory with the application.
How do I disable log creation? File contents:

```
conn=0x78be4c043a50, PGAPI_DriverConnect( in)='DRIVER={psqlodbcw.so};Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=TEST_DB;Uid=postgres;Pwd=1;Debug=0;FileUsage=1;Trace=0;CommLog=0;MyLog=0;', fDriverCompletion=0
```

Editing the postgres configuration file did not help, there is a suspicion that it is written by odbc-driver.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This website is **English only**, either rewrite your post or use the Russian website: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: Are you sure this is coming from Postgres and not the mystery app that you haven't named? Either way, this doesn't look like a programming question. It's a question for whoever wrote / maintains that app, or it's a database administration question.

Comment: this is not a mysterious application, this is my application under development. This log is written by unixodbc driver. It is disabled by the CommLog=0 parameter in odbc.ini. But I need to connect without a dsn file, but just a string. I looked at the source code of the driver, it does not process this parameter when transmitting the connection string, but simply takes it from odbc.ini. So the question is closed